# Python defaultdict throws KeyError with default_factory set?

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter, defaultdict

Im working on a small program that uses tkinter to build a gui and a dictionary (that is stored in a json file) to save settings. This is the relevant code:

import:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from json import dump, load
```

definition:

```
def vivdict(preload={}):
    return defaultdict(vivdict, preload)
```

loading:

```
try:
    with open('config.json', 'r') as jsonFile:
        self._config = vivdict(load(jsonFile))
except FileNotFoundError:
    self._config = vivdict()
```

and this is the error i get:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Leonhard/Documents/git/changeMAC/changeMAC.py", line 97, in _cbDropdown
    var = self._config['adapterSettings'][self._currentAdapter]['changeOnRestart']
KeyError: '0003'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Leonhard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:/Users/Leonhard/Documents/git/changeMAC/changeMAC.py", line 110, in _cbCheckbutton
    self._config['adapterSettings'][self._currentAdapter]['changeOnRestart'] = self._tkvar2.get()
KeyError: '0003
```

Im quite confused because defaultdict with default_factory set shouldn't throw a KeyError? Right?

Comment: `self._config` is a `defaultdict` type. What type is `self._config['adapterSettings']`? My guess is a normal `dict`

Comment: It'll apply to missing keys in `self._config`, but you're then going in to dictionaries within that and they're presumably not `defaultdict`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in saying that `defaultdict` can't throw a `KeyError` but look at your code. First do `self._config['adapterSettings']` then you index that with `[self._currentAdapter]`. I think the problem might be that `self._config['adapterSettings']` is a normal `dict` so you need to change your loading script to convert all of the elements that `load(jsonFile)` returns into `defaultdict`.

Change your `vivdict` function to:

```py
def vivdict(preload={}):
    for key, value in preload.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict): # Convert all `dict`s to `defaultdict`
            preload[key] = vivdict(value)
    return defaultdict(vivdict, preload)
```

Comment: Thank you. Really didn't think of that. It seems like the sub-entries are converted to a dict when dumped and loaded into/from json.